# Frenet formulas of $\alpha(t)=(t,t^{2},t^{3})$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

Given the following curve
$$\alpha(t)=(t,t^{2},t^{3})$$
I gotta find its Frenet vectors. I know, for example
$$N(t)=\frac{\alpha'(t)\times(\alpha''(t)\times\alpha'(t))}{||\alpha'(t)||\cdot||\alpha''(t)\times\alpha'(t)||}$$
So, in my case, I found that
$$N(t)=\frac{(-4t-18t^3,12-18t^4,6t+12t^3)}{2\sqrt{(1+4t^{2}+9t^{4})\cdot(9t^{4}+9t^{2}+1)}}$$
which is a not so elegant expression. Then, what am I doing is correct? Or is there a easier way to evaluate it?

Comment: I don't have the time to check computations, but your result does not seem weird at all. Most curves do not have any type of symmetry that would suggest that cancellations would happen. Even more so for a twisted cubic like yours. Frenet formulas in concrete cases aren't nice, in general.